# Blender integration with c#

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, blender

I've been following a Tree+Leaves tutorial for blender, as i am populating the tree with the leaves i wonder if by exporting it to C# (WPF) will it make every leaf as a "single object" so that i can add some kind of behavior into a single leaf that i pick from the tree.

For example, what i want to do is to be able to make random leaves fall as a certain event occurs, controlling its animation while falling and making it stay on the ground for a certain period of time and at the end of a long period of time the tree will be partially naked.

Thanks in advance
~Regards

Answer (score 0):

Blender only provides a python API. So you can't do it from Blender directly. Thus you have to export your tree and leafs from Blender into a format that can be used by one of the c# 3d engines and take it from there.